# Populate a SQLite database from a website

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

I searched a bit and couldn't find anything so I'm asking it here:

It'd be great if there's a tutorial or example project where I can look at. So far I've only found on how to populate this database using the data that is generated locally, by programmer's input.

Question:
I have an URL to a website that is a .txt with some data, how do I parse it, populate it to a SQLite database that I'll create in my Android application?

Edit:
This is the format:

```
Item1 <newline>
Description <newline>
LocalFilePathToPicture1<newline>
Item2 <newline>
Description <newline>
LocalFilePathToPicture2<newline>
...
```

Comment: In which format your data is ? Is that a JSON formatted data in the link or something else, please make the question clear on this.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I have added the format in my edit. a <newline> characters delineates each piece string of information. Local path to tile name is on the same server and in the same location as the file.

Comment: You've got a broad question here. 1) a network request for a file 2) parsing a file 3) storing parsed info in a sqlite database. I suggest you break your research into these individual parts

Comment: @JasmineRain I've added a template for simply reading the text. Try it and for further reading do research..

Answer (score 0):

Ok as your comments and latest edits, lets say your text file url is something like this

```
http://www.example.com/myTextFile.txt
```

What you can do something like this

```
StringBuffer myString = new StringBuffer("");
try {
    // Create a URL
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/myTextFile.txt");

    // Read the text
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

  String string;
    while ((string = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // string is one line of text; readLine() reads the newline
    myString.append("__"+string);
    }
    in.close();


}
 catch (Exception e) {
} 

return myString;
```

And here is a sample of doInBackground() method inside your `AsyncTask` class where you will be splitting the string and inserting them into sqlite

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String myString = params[0];
      String[] splitedString = myString.split("__");

     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

      cv.put("firstline", splitedString[0]); //where firstline is your column name
      cv.put("secondline", splitedString[1]);

     db.insert(yourTable, null, cv); //where db is your instance of writable database
     db.close(); //Close the connection
    }
```

Comment: You're missing the fact that this needs an AsyncTask and the whole sqlite thing

Comment: I assume I parse the string and store them to SQLite inside the while loop?

Comment: @cricket_007 How can we write all the sqlite codes and AsyncTask to insert the data then, It's just a guideline to read the text.

Comment: @JasmineRain you can simply split up your string returned by this statement and use AsyncTask or anything else to insert data in sqlite. What is the further confusion then..

Comment: You don't have to answer, you can comment with links to other posts but if you're going to answer, you should at least post a full answer.

Comment: @JasmineRain I have added some sample to insert them in sqlite, please tell if there still some issue left.

Comment: @JasmineRain will you please let me know if it worked or not ?